# How to bind service from Java library in Xamarin Android Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-binding, xamarin-native

- I have service class implementation in Example.aar

  public class DemoService : Service{}
- I have created a Native binding library project.
- When i tried to bind this service in Xamarin.Android project.  bindService() is returning false.

  ```
  var Result =context.getApplicationContext.bindService(new Intent(context,typeof(DemoService)), new ServiceConnection(),Bind.AutoCreate); //Result is false.
  ```

How to bind a service created in 3rd party library project in Xamarin Android project.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this article [Binding a Java Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar).
In the Microsoft doc, first you can get the class from the .aar file.

```
var ClassName = new Com.MyCompany.MyProject.MyclassName();
```

Then use the bindService or other methods to use the Class.

```
var Result =context.getApplicationContext.bindService(new Intent(context,typeof(ClassName)), new ServiceConnection(),Bind.AutoCreate);
```